# Missing or presenting body-tag placeholder in SXA

Tags: sxa, presentation, placeholders

I have got two sample websites, both just have created tenant and site with SXA 1.8. When I am creating a page and open it in EE, I am getting two different visual editing structures.

**1.** Three placeholders (`header`, `main`, `footer`) taking a central part of a page. Same as shown in numerous demos:
[image: 3 placeholders layout]

**2.** Four placeholders taking entire width of a page: `body-top` following by those 3 mentioned above: `header`, `main`, `footer`
[image]

I am wondering in a reason for such a misconsistency, trying to identify the difference, however, nothing found.

- These both pages have Page template inheriting the same exact set of base templates (all from SXA)
- These both pages have Page template inheriting the same exact set of base templates (all coming from SXA)
- I also checked Standard Values item for that template and both look identical.
- Actual Page items I am opening in EE, that has derived from Page templates also are similar - no fields differenced at least.
- Final Layouts are the same, no controls, both using MVC Layout view coming with SXA out of the box.
- Still compared both layout files (`/Views/SxaLayout/SxaLayout.cshtml`) to confirm they match byte-to-byte, both have the structure described in the official SXA documentation (https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/the-html-structure-of-pages-and-renderings.html). Yes, they both have `body-top` placeholder within layout (and also `body-bottom` which I am not seeing in both cases for some reason), as described in the doc.

Opening DevTool is browser gave me the difference, explaining why one is shown but not another:

```
<code type="text/sitecore" id="scEnclosingTag_" chrometype="placeholder" kind="close" hintname="body-top" class="scpm">
</code>
```

vs.

```
<code type="text/sitecore" chrometype="placeholder" kind="open" id="body_top" key="body-top" class="scpm" data-selectable="true">
... large json data inside...
</code>
```

Therefore the question is: **why** is the behaviour different and **how to**  make it consistent (to either of layouts or the "right" one)? How do I control this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment under Patric's post, I did not come to a precise answer on what exactly is breaking, however after spending decent time I have identified that Themes for that SXA website is breaking out, so had to replace it entirely (from my blog post):

> Finally, after spending plenty of time I figured out that something
>   was wrong with SXA themes. Unfortunately, did not identify what
>   exactly causes the problem, but after re-creating it at serialization
>   config and re-serializing items the issue has gone. 
>   So, the outcome is: if you see unexpected placeholders - please make sure your SXA
>   theme is in the correct state and serialized properly.

More info if the issue and how I troubleshooted it: http://blog.martinmiles.net/post/mythical-sxa-body-top-placeholder

Comment: Hi @Martin Miles , i am facing the same issues on one of my development environments , i tried creating a new theme for the site and associated the theme to the site , this did not fix the issue , any suggestions on how you fixed the issue ?

Comment: @SitecoreNoob that got fixed in latest SXA 1.8.1

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the poster has solved the issue by now and posted about this in his Blog:
http://blog.martinmiles.net/post/mythical-sxa-body-top-placeholder

Comment: Unfortunately there is no precise answer, but I will update here below anyway